# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "coding": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin

Hi I am creating an Android application that allows the title, content, price, number(1), and image to be stored in the database when I write on the bulletin board. An error occurs while registering the publication to the database.
I've been thinking about it for days, but I don't know why.

Below is my error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project, PID: 2816
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "coding": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO writing (title, content, price, person, count, image) VALUES (test coding, this is test, 3000, 2, 1, ?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1070)
        at com.example.swu_guru.GroupBuyingWrite$onCreate$2.onClick(GroupBuyingWrite.kt:97)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This is database class (MyDBHelper.kt)

```
package com.example.project

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class MyDBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "gbDB", null, 1){
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db!!.execSQL("CREATE TABLE writing (" + "title text, " +
                "content text, " + "price INTEGER, " + "person INTEGER, " + "count INTEGER, " + "image BLOB);")
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {

    }
}
```

This is creating post part. (GroupBuyingWrite.kt)

And the debug indicates that there is an error in part `var stmt: SQLiteStatement = sqlitedb.compileStatement(insQuery)` of this class.

```
        btnGBWregister.setOnClickListener {

            sqlitedb = myDBHelper.writableDatabase

            var title: String ?= edtGBWtitle.text.toString()
            var content: String = edtGBWcontent.text.toString()
            var price: String = edtGBWprice.text.toString()
            var person: String = edtGBWperson.text.toString()
            var count: String = GBWcount.toString()
            var image: Drawable = imgGBWimageview.drawable
            var byteArray: ByteArray ?= null


            try {
                val bitmapDrawable = image as BitmapDrawable?
                val bitmap = bitmapDrawable?.bitmap
                val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
                byteArray = stream.toByteArray()
                Log.d("image save", "image saving")
            } catch (cce: ClassCastException) {Log.d("image null", "image null")}

          

            var insQuery: String = "INSERT INTO writing (title, content, price, person, count, image) " +
                    "VALUES ($title, $content, $price, $person, $count, ?)"
            var stmt: SQLiteStatement = sqlitedb.compileStatement(insQuery)
            stmt.bindBlob(1, byteArray)
            stmt.execute()
        }
```

Comment: use parameters for all variable not only for `byteArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is because the strings are not enclosed in single quotes.

So instead of `"VALUES ($title, $content, $price, $person, $count, ?)"`

You should have `"VALUES ('$title', '$content', $price, $person, $count, ?)"`

However, it is better to bind the values, so  `"VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"` with the appropriate `stmnt.bind....`'s

So :-

```
        var insQuery: String = "INSERT INTO writing (title, content, price, person, count, image) " +
                "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        var stmt: SQLiteStatement = sqlitedb.compileStatement(insQuery)
        stmt.bindString(1,title)
        stmt.bndString(2,content)
        stmt.bndString(3,price)
        stmt.bindString(4,person)
        stmt.bindString(5,count)
        stmt.bindBlob(6,byteArray)
        stmt.execute()
```

An alternative would be to utilise the SQLiteDatabase [`insert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) convenience method along with the values placed into a `ContentValues`.

Which could be :-

```
    var cv: ContentValues = ContentValues()
    cv.put("title",title)
    cv.put("content",content)
    cv.put("price",price)
    cv.put("person",person)
    cv.put("count",count)
    cv.put("image",image)
    var rowid = sqlitedb.insert("writing",null,cv) //rowid will be the rowid of the inserted row else -1 if row couldn't be inserted
```

- Note that the `insert` method is equivalent of `INSERT OR IGNORE ....`, so really to fully reflect your SQL you would use the  `insertOrThrow` method.
- The `insert` method has the advantage, as commented, that it returns the rowid of the inserted row or -1 if the row couldn't be inserted. It also builds the underlying SQL (according to the columns specified in the ContententValues (the first parameter of the put)). The values themselves are bound.

Comment: @user16452112, if you found that the answer helped then please consider ticking it as answered.